# Why did I a get a Bad Archive Mirror?

Tags: mirrors

When I was installing Ubuntu non physical address extension (pae) 12.04 onto my IBM T42 type 2378, I got a bad archive mirror.

I live in the USA.  I selected the default archive mirror `us.ubuntu.com`. I also got this message

```
to get more info check /var/log/sys/og or virtual console 4.
```

I do not know what that means and where to go to get the report.

Answer (score 2):

Official Ubuntu archive for USA is located at address: `us.archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: You are correct.  When I selected US as the country for the archive mirror, the default was us.archive.ubuntu.com. I selected the default, however, I received a message that it was a bad archive mirror. I do not know what to do. I selected other countries and still got a bad archive mirror. Would you please advice?

Answer (score 1):

You must edit your sources.list and change `us.ubuntu.com` for `us.archive.ubuntu.com`, you can do this with the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i '/us\.u/us.archive.u/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will correct your mirror.

Comment: I selected US for the country for the archive mirror.  As a result, there was an automatic default which was us.archive.ubuntu.com.  I do not know what you meant by I can change the sources.list for us.archive.ubuntu.com to the terminal sudo sed -i '/us\.u/us.archive.u/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.  I did not get an option that allowed me to make a change. Would you please provide me with detail instructions on how I can change it to the terminal? Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: The changes were already made, if you run `sudo apt-get update` they should be applied already. If not, **edit your question** and add more information.

Comment: I have a IBM T42 type 2378 which doesn't have an operating system at all. I downloaded the non pae ubuntu onto a cd.  As I was answering the questions, I came to the archive mirror section which required the country which then provided me with the mirror that failed. What's sudo apt-get update?  How do I run sudo apt-get update?  Where do I find sudo apt-get update? Was I suppose to run it before I install ubuntu?

Comment: @Jacquie I don't have the sightless idea of what you are talking about. I don't even know if you installed Ubuntu or how. I recommend you editing your question and **include step by step** all the actions that you have took until this moment, what are you planning to reach (aka goal) and what is the problem you are facing right now. Also the logs that inform us what is happening any kind of information on screen in valuable.